# What does affect a container's dimensions?

Tags: html, css

So I have the following structure:

```
<div id="bannerLogin" class="topBannerAnon">
    <a href="http://www.redacted.fr/" class="logo" target="_blank">
        <img src="redacted" style="border:none;">
    </a>
</div>
```

With no CSS, the containing div extends to the image height, which is on the left side of the div.

Now I want to put that image on the right of the div instead of the natural left. If I use `float: right;` on the `.logo` class, the `<a>` element is taken out of the flow so my containing div won't extend to the picture height anymore (it will have a height=0).
I tried to wrap the `<a>` element into another div and give the `logo` class to it (in case it needs to be a block element), but same behaviour.

So I'm realizing I have no idea how to attach an element on the right of its container, with the container still taking into account the dimensions of said element. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing fine, you just need a clearing element before you close your container in order to make the floated elements "occupy" the parent's space. Something like this should work:

```
<div id="bannerLogin" class="topBannerAnon">
    <a href="http://www.redacted.fr/" class="logo" target="_blank">
        <img src="redacted" style="border:none;">
    </a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.clear {clear: both;}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of images, you can use the traditional html `align="right"` tag to put the image on right side of the content and keep the other aspects of styling the same.

The `align="right"` tag goes in the `IMG` html element.

Comment: The parent of the image is an anchor, so that wouldn't work unless you set the anchor width to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Given this CSS:

```
.logo {
  float: right;
}
```

… you can get the `div` to grow by adding this CSS:

```
#bannerLogin {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

That's due to the fact that an overflow with a value different from visible creates a new [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context).

**Snippet**

```css
#bannerLogin {
  background: #fed;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.logo {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="bannerLogin" class="topBannerAnon">
    <a href="http://www.redacted.fr/" class="logo" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" style="border:none;">
    </a>
</div>
```